# Update a specific key in JSON Array using PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON file which has some key-value pairs in Arrays. I need to update/replace the value for key **id** with a value stored in a variable called **Var1**

The problem is that when I run my python code, it adds the new key-value pair in outside the inner array instead of replacing:

**PYTHON SCRIPT**:

```py
import json
import sys
var1=abcdefghi

with open('C:\\Projects\\scripts\\input.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data['id'] = var1
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))
    f.truncate()
```

**INPUT JSON**:

```
{
    "channel": "AT",
    "username": "Maintenance",
    "attachments": [
      {
         "fallback":"[Urgent]:",
         "pretext":"[Urgent]:",
         "color":"#D04000",
         "fields":[
            {
               "title":"SERVERS:",
               "id":"popeye",
               "short":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{
    "username": "Maintenance", 
    "attachments": [
        {
            "color": "#D04000", 
            "pretext": "[Urgent]:", 
            "fallback": "[Urgent]:", 
            "fields": [
                {
                    "short": false, 
                    "id": "popeye", 
                    "title": "SERVERS:"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "channel": "AT", 
    "id": "abcdefghi"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Below will update the id inside fields :

```
json_data['attachments'][0]['fields'][0]['id'] = var1
```

Comment: @AswaryTiwari Welcome, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

To add to the earlier answer from akash, here is a way that you can make these changes in the event that you have multiple fields that contain ids that you want to change to this same variable. I know this likely wouldn't apply here (given that it is an id), but could be used as a broad example for when you want to set all values to the same value in a similar type of question. For example, if you wanted to set the id number for many fields to be unique, you could set `var1 = 1` and then each time the `for k in json_data` loops, you increase the value of var1 by 1. This is not the example I have below, the example below would be to change all the Fields so they all have the same ID value.

Further adjustments can be made if you had multiple attachments as well (could not just use `[attachments][0]` as it'd only apply to the fields within the first attachment).

I just figured this knowledge could be good for someone to have at some point.

**INPUT JSON**

```
{
  "channel": "AT",
  "username": "Maintenance",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "fallback": "[Urgent]:",
      "pretext": "[Urgent]:",
      "color": "#D04000",
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "SERVERS:",
          "id": "popeye",
          "short": false
        },
        {
          "title": "DUMMYDATA:",
          "id": "DORRIS",
          "short": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**CODE**

```
var1 = 'abcdefghi'
json_file = "Some/file/path"
with open(json_file, 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    for k in json_data['attachments'][0]['fields']:
        k['id'] = var1
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2))
    f.truncate()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "channel": "AT",
  "username": "Maintenance",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "fallback": "[Urgent]:",
      "pretext": "[Urgent]:",
      "color": "#D04000",
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "SERVERS:",
          "id": "abcdefghi",
          "short": false
        },
        {
          "title": "DUMMYDATA:",
          "id": "abcdefghi",
          "short": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope that this is useful to some extent.